# parallel programming - Performance Improvement

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am writing a controller using SpringBoot, my controller is like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public MyDto getData throws Exception{

    try{

        Mydto=new MyDto();
        dto.setFirstName(someImpl.getFirstName());
        dto.setLastName(someOtherImpl.getLastName());

        dto.setAddress1(someImpl.getAddress1());
        dto.setAddress2(someOtherImpl.getAddress2());
        return dto;

       }catch(){...}
```

Here someImpl and someOtherImpl are interfaces in which it contains a some method declartion, we fetching **getFirstName** and **getLastName** from Database, but **getAddress1** and **getAddress2** is hardcoded value, How can I make first two settter(firstname and lastname ) to run in one thread and last two setters(Address1 and Address2) to run in another thread parallaly so i can reduce a time to fetch my data.

Comment: Using multiple threads will *not* make this faster. The cost of the context switching will far outweigh the trivial cost of making a few method calls (unless you are doing a lot of work in the setters).

Comment: can you explain a bit more? why we cant make this faster? Or any other solution in which i can make this fast ?

Comment: More importantly, why do you think that threading should make it faster?

Comment: By analogy: If you have 2 cars driving along a road, building another road isn't going to help the cars get there any faster. For one thing, you've got to wait until the road is built; then you've got to drive the car onto the other road; the cars can still only drive at the same top speed; etc.

Comment: I agree with you , can't we use parallel processing here ?

Comment: You can use parallel processing: it's just going to be slower than what it already does.

Comment: Then how can i make this fast ? right now its taking ~10 sec to get a Json response. i need to reduce that time atleast ~2-3 sec.

Comment: If it takes 10s, then the problem is something completely different. What exactly (!) takes 10s? It cannot be setters themselves. Connecting to db? External service?

Comment: This is micro-optimization.  Did you measure the time a setter method takes?  Assuming it’s just changing the value of a private field, the time is probably measured in nanoseconds.  Just how much faster do you think can it get?

Comment: A solution would be to use [CompleatableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to retrieve the details and set them into the dto. Check [Guide To CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture) for details

Comment: @ValentinCarnu: the guy has something like 10s latency somewhere, no threads will help him

Comment: Indeed, though maybe the latency is 5s somewhere and 5s somewhere else, in this case threads could help if the operations are done async

Answer (score 2):

> logic is there, SomeImpl will fetch ~15 records from DB then that will sent to mapper , mapper will filter ~5 fields from 15, then it will set those 5 values to Dto.

that you need to specify upfront

Fetching 15 records from DB takes 10s .. that's too much. I'd still guess the problem is somewhere else until you prove otherwise

Here we will assume that parallel processing will help you (thread switching and managing will take less then each operation). Please note that reading data in parallel from a database may help you less than you'd expect. With other words - this is how to do operations in parallel, but I still do not believe it will solve your issue.

You may really read resources from the comment

> A solution would be to use CompleatableFuture to retrieve the details
>        and set them into the dto. Check [Guide To CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) 
>       for details – Valentin Carnu

You may use an executor service with a fixed thread pool

```
private static final ExecutorService fetchService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```

Submit your tasks

```
final Mydto myDto =new MyDto();
Collection<Future> futures = ...
futures.add(fetchService.submit(() -> { myDto.setSometing(...); }));
futures.add(fetchService.submit(() -> { myDto.setSometingElse(...); }));
// wait until all completes assuming no other thread submit tasks
futures.forEach(f->{f.get();});
```

I wrote it from my head no validating syntax properly, but you should have the idea

Comment: I agree with you , see let me explain a bit , I am calling ~12 Impl from my controller out of 12 Impl , 9 will call DB and in avg each impl will fetch  ~15-20 records then goes to mapper and set it in Dto. Now you can imagine why its taking ~10

Comment: @VinayHegde good :) I really hope the parallel processing will help you (though I am skeptic by default, nothing personal). Now I see you may want to cast the lambdas to Runnable(I have no java here to validate)